# p5.js: Let the computer draw something

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I would like to let the computer draw something. It should look like a human is drawing something on a paper, with random values.

This is my try:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(30);
}

function draw() {
  x1 = random(500);
  y1 = random(500);
  x2 = random(500);
  y2 = random(500);
  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

So at the moment, it just puts random lines on top of each other. But it should result in one long connected scribble with curves, like this:

[image]

How is it possible to code it like that?

Comment: This question is *way* too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. What would constitute  "*looking like a human is drawing something on a paper*", exactly? What parameters are you using to evaluate the output? What is "*something*"? What differentiates drawing on paper versus another medium to you specifically? With the answers to those questions in mind, what research have you done to get closer to this state before posting here?

Comment: _"This is my try, and it unfortunately doesn't look like what I wish at all:"_ What do you wish it to look like?

Comment: I am not sure how to explain. At the moment, it just puts random lines on top of each other. But it should look like an organic drawing. How would you describe that?

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps a little. Still not perfect but possible approach to play with and further advance ;-) Have a fun with

```js
var x1, y1, x2=250, y2=250, maxVal = 500;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(maxVal, maxVal);
  frameRate(30);
}

// just uncomment one line, comment another and do restart please
// var a = 2, b = 1;
 var a = 40, b = 20;
// var a = 100, b = 50;
//var a = 200, b = 100;

function draw() {

  function tryFix(val) {

    let res = val < 0 ? 0 : val > maxVal ? maxVal : val;

    return res;

  }

  dx = random(a)-b;
  dy = random(a)-b;
  x1 = x2;
  y1 = y2;
  x = x2 + dx;
  y = y2 + dy;
  x = tryFix(x);
  y = tryFix(y);
  x2 = x;
  y2 = y;
  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I should add, this is similar to the random walker seen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l__fEY1xanY

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!